# How exactly do you configure httpOnlyCookies in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, xss, httponly

Inspired by this CodingHorror article, "[Protecting Your Cookies: HttpOnly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001167.html)"

How do you set this property? Somewhere in the web config?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET 2.0 or greater, you can turn it on in the Web.config file. In the <system.web> section, add the following line:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried "<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>" and neither settings works.

Comment: @rolls I have the same problem. Did you find a solution or cause?

Answer (score 12):

With props to Rick (second comment down in the blog post mentioned), here's the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcookiessection.httponlycookies.aspx) on httpOnlyCookies.

Bottom line is that you just add the following section in your system.web section in your web.config:

```
<httpCookies domain="" httpOnlyCookies="true|false" requireSSL="true|false" />
```

Comment: By the way - don't actually use domain="String" - either set a valid domain or leave that attribute out.

Comment: @Dillie-O what can cause this element to be locked? when i set it in my web.config file, i get the following error "the element httpcookies has been locked in a higher level configuration"

Comment: @StackTrace - You might check your machine.config file on the server itself to see if that has a setting that has locked things.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to do it in code, use the [System.Web.HttpCookie.HttpOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly.aspx) property.

This is directly from the MSDN docs:

```
// Create a new HttpCookie.
HttpCookie myHttpCookie = new HttpCookie("LastVisit", DateTime.Now.ToString());
// By default, the HttpOnly property is set to false 
// unless specified otherwise in configuration.
myHttpCookie.Name = "MyHttpCookie";
Response.AppendCookie(myHttpCookie);
// Show the name of the cookie.
Response.Write(myHttpCookie.Name);
// Create an HttpOnly cookie.
HttpCookie myHttpOnlyCookie = new HttpCookie("LastVisit", DateTime.Now.ToString());
// Setting the HttpOnly value to true, makes
// this cookie accessible only to ASP.NET.
myHttpOnlyCookie.HttpOnly = true;
myHttpOnlyCookie.Name = "MyHttpOnlyCookie";
Response.AppendCookie(myHttpOnlyCookie);
// Show the name of the HttpOnly cookie.
Response.Write(myHttpOnlyCookie.Name);
```

Doing it in code allows you to selectively choose which cookies are HttpOnly and which are not.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly putting `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false"/>` doesn't seem to disable `httpOnlyCookies` in ASP.NET 2.0. Check this article about [SessionID and Login Problems With ASP .NET 2.0](http://nerd.steveferson.com/2007/09/14/act-sessionid-and-login-problems-with-asp-net-20/).

Looks like Microsoft took the decision to not allow you to disable it from the web.config. Check this [post on forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/p/976773/1240648.aspx)