# Is it possible to implement "Remember Me" using jquery cookies?

Tags: jquery, cookies, remember-me

Is it possible to implement "Remember Me" using jquery? If so, any suggestion how it can be done?

**EDIT:**

I am trying to remember username and password using jquery cookies.store cookies about username and password and read it the next time and redirect to a specific page.

Comment: More information please.

Comment: why would you store `username and password` as cookies? can't it be any other variables?

Comment: @Reigel thats what i am asking suggestion how it can be done? Please suggest possible ways of doing it?

Comment: it depends on what are you trying to achieve. I see you want to redirect to a page, but is it necessary for you to use username and password? `username` might be okay, but I doubt with `password`. why not something like `username` and `logged` ? `logged` would be a boolean with value depending if the user is logged or not.

Comment: @Reigel logged holds a value `True` until the user logs out. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: But what if the user faked the cookie to have value of True for logged. He can login without password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

[jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

How to implement:

- [Store login information in cookie using jQuery](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/02/20/store-login-information-in-cookie-using-jquery/)
- [Using Simple JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Comment: @Naveed this isn't an answer what i was looking for. I know this plugin but i want suggestions to implement "Remember Me" using this jquery cookie plugin.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: I have added a tutorial to implement this.

Comment: @Reigel i ve removed -1. But this answer uses password as cookie value. Is that secure?

Comment: I'm not really sure about security. But why would I put that on the risk. Well, that tutorial is the way to go. Use other variables as you like. You can use password if you really want to. I just don't suggest it. `logged holds a value True until the user logs out.` is what i'm suggesting.

Comment: May be this thread will help to understand cookie security: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100356/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-in-cookies