# MVC Reference difference (User.Identity.Name)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make a MVC application. In my _LoginPartial.cshtml,

I can use User.Identity.Name variable, which gives the username of current session, though any reference was specified otherwise.  So, likewise, I thought User.Identity.Name would be also available in Global.asax, but it's not.
My login system saves the username and password in cookie. 
Is there a way to recall the current username in Global.asax?

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot use `User.Identity.Name`? What error are you getting? I also wouldn't advise reading the username from a cookie. A cookie can easily be modified and they can then pretend to be another user.

Comment: User.Identity.Name works fine in my global.asax

Comment: Try using the full name, i.e.: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
Wether you can use it or not in the global.asax file probably depends on *where* you want to use it, in what method.

Comment: I keep getting this error.  an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property 'system.web.httpapplication.user.get'

Comment: @user3734823 Show us your code, but I think you are attempting to use an instance member from a static method, change your method to be non-static.

Comment: Btw [is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-in-cookies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100356/is-it-secure-to-store-passwords-in-cookies)