# How to get .authcookie in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies, selenium

I am using **IE 11** for the following case.

I have a web site with asp.net login.

After I login on the site, I write into the browser debugger console *document.cookie* This will return some cookies that contain "__utma, __utmb, __utmz" but not the .authcookie and ASP.NET._SessionId.

In Fiddler ( and in the debugger tool's network traffic monitor) I can see the .authcookie and ASP.NET._SessionId were created and set to a value.

How can I get these cookies in javascript?

I need these cookies for a Selenium test.

Comment: Your problem lies in the fact that those cookies are HttpOnly. This might be of some help : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2905847/1236044