# 'HttpOnly' should be added to 'auth' cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, cookie-httponly

I've recently had a security audit on my website and was informed I need to apply 'HttpOnly' to my 'auth' cookie.

I have no idea how to change this in the web.config file.

The site is ASP.NET MVC.

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly do you configure httpOnlyCookies in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529/how-exactly-do-you-configure-httponlycookies-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Web.config**

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" …>
```

**Or Via C# Code**

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("cookieName");
cookie.HttpOnly = true;
Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I actually tried this previously but I must of made a mistake with the location of the code in the web.config.  Works great.  Thanks for your help.